# Getting a SQL query to print 0 for null count results across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get a SQL query to give me the results of a count but I need the result to include rows where the count is 0. What I found for solutions to this was to use `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` in place of `COUNT(*)` however that had no effect on the result. I also tried using a `LEFT JOIN` but SQL gave me a syntax error if I tried to put in those. Here's my table setup

User

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UserID      | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName   | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName    | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Protocol    | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Endpoint    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UsergroupID | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Subscription

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SubscriptionID | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TopicID        | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| UserID         | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Topic

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| TopicID  | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| FBName   | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FBToken  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TWName   | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TWToken  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TWSecret | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My SQL query to try and get the COUNT is :

```
SELECT Topic.TopicID as ID, Topic.Name AS TopicName, COUNT(*) AS numSubscriptions
FROM User, Topic, Subscription
WHERE Subscription.UserID = User.UserID
  AND Subscription.TopicID = Topic.TopicID
GROUP BY Topic.TopicID;
```

I've tried replacing `COUNT(*)` with `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` and I've tried to replace `User,Topic,Subscription` with `User JOIN Subscription JOIN Topic` and I also tried `User LEFT JOIN Subscription LEFT JOIN Topic` but that got a SQL error.

The output I'm getting is:

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| ID | TopicName | numSubscriptions |
+----+-----------+------------------+
|  2 | test      |                2 |
|  3 | test2     |                1 |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

I need to be getting

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| ID | TopicName | numSubscriptions |
+----+-----------+------------------+
|  2 | test      |                2 |
|  3 | test2     |                1 |
|  4 | test3     |                0 |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, outer joins are left to right. So, the trick is to start with Topic:

```
SELECT Topic.TopicID as ID, Topic.Name AS TopicName,
  COUNT(User.UserID) AS numSubscriptions
FROM Topic
LEFT JOIN Subscription
  ON Subscription.TopicID = Topic.TopicID
JOIN User
  ON User.UserID = Subscription.UserID
GROUP BY Topic.TopicID
```

This allows for multiple subscriptions per user and requires that the user record exists to be considered in the count.

`COUNT(NULL)` evaluates to `0`, so any topic records without a corresponding subscription and user record will show as `0`.

If you're not concerned whether the user record exists, you could simplify it to the following:

```
SELECT Topic.TopicID as ID, Topic.Name AS TopicName,
  COUNT(Subscription.TopicID) AS numSubscriptions
FROM Topic
LEFT JOIN Subscription
  ON Subscription.TopicID = Topic.TopicID
GROUP BY Topic.TopicID
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below should do what you're after. The column in the COUNT() can be any column of the subscription table, but using its ID is a good practice.

Using the left join ensures that all entries of the user table will show up in the results, even if there are no matching subscriptions.

```
SELECT User.firstName,
       User.lastName,
       Topic.Name AS TopicName,
       COUNT(Subscription.SubscriptionId) AS numSubscriptions
FROM USER
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscription ON Subscription.UserID=USER.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Topic ON Subscription.TopicID=Topic.TopicID
GROUP BY User.firstName, User.lastName, Topic.Name;
```

Comment: This still doesn't get me the row with 0 entries for the test3 topic. Also, I edited the question, I accidentally put in the wrong query at first I don't actually care about the User's name for this query.